# New server with software RAID: how to split the root partition into root+ home

Tags: server, partitioning

I'm on my first dedicated server.

When I set up a minimal Ubuntu 16.04 server and ssh on it I find:

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal ~ # df -lh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6,3G   13M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/md2        438G  1,1G  414G   1% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M   60M  403M  13% /boot
tmpfs           6,3G     0  6,3G   0% /run/user/0
```

I normally set /home and / partition separately, but here I had no partition choice.

How do I shrink / to let's say 30 GB and keep the rest to /home ?

**EDIT:** The hosting company also offers a "rescue" system, a Linux live environment that allows to have administrative access to the server. The environment starts from the network (PXE boot) and runs in the memory of the server. This makes it possible to carry out repairs to the installed system, to check file systems or to install a new operating system.

Should I use this system to shrink the root partition first ?

**EDIT 2:** The server uses software RAID:

```
$cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      33521664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      465895744 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [==================>..]  resync = 94.5% (440301824/465895744) finish=4.2min speed=100467K/sec
      bitmap: 1/4 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you  want separated partitions?

Comment: I normally keep separate partitions in order to reinstall/update the OS keeping users data..